# Trouble configuring TeamCity and dotCover

Tags: teamcity, nunit-2.5, dotcover

Im trying to configure TeamCity 6.5 with inbuilt NUNIT and bundled dotCover. For reasons I do not understand dotCover Merge command fails, along with all subsequent commands with some non-zero exit code.

Using Nunit 2.5.10, x64 on a 64 bit machine, with .NET4.0 runtime for nunit. I selected dotCover as the coverage tool, left blank to use the inbuilt dotCover, and my filters look like this:

```
+:BSF
-:Aspose.Cells
-:BSF.UnitTest
-:BSF.IntegrationTests
-:DataAnnotationsExtensions.ClientValidation
-:DataAnnotationsExtensions
-:Elmah
-:FluentNHibernate
-:Iesi.Collections
-:NHibernate
-:Ninject
-:NLog
-:nunit.framework
-:nunit.mocks
-:pnunit.framework
-:Rhino.Mocks
-:WebActivator
-:Yahoo.Yui.Compressor
```

And here is the build log :

```
    Step 2/2] Coverage session finished [2/19/2012 5:16:06 PM]
[17:16:06]: [Step 2/2] Coverage results post-processing started [2/19/2012 5:16:06 PM]
[17:16:06]: [Step 2/2] Coverage results post-processing finished [2/19/2012 5:16:06 PM]
[17:16:06]: [Step 2/2] ##teamcity[importData type='dotNetCoverage' tool='dotcover' file='C:\System\TeamCity\Agent007\temp\buildTmp\tmpEB31.tmp']
[17:16:06]: [Step 2/2] Importing data from 'C:\System\TeamCity\Agent007\temp\buildTmp\tmpEB31.tmp' with 'dotNetCoverage' processor
[17:16:06]: [Step 2/2] Process exited with code 0
[17:16:06]: Waiting for 1 service processes to complete
[17:16:06]: Processing 1 coverage report(s)
[17:16:06]: Generating coverage report by dotcover for files: [C:\System\TeamCity\Agent007\temp\buildTmp\tmpEB31.tmp]
[17:16:06]: Get dotCover version (1s)
[17:16:08]: [Get dotCover version] Started dotCover: C:\System\TeamCity\buildAgent\tools\dotCover\dotCover.exe version C:\System\TeamCity\Agent007\temp\buildTmp\dotCover1818874175934681230Version
[17:16:08]: [Get dotCover version] Output: JetBrains dotCover Console Runner v1.1.252.2. Copyright (c) 2009-2012 JetBrains s.r.o. All rights reserved.

[17:16:08]: [Get dotCover version] dotCover exited with code: 0
[17:16:08]: Use DotCover 1.1.x commands set
[17:16:08]: Merge dotCover reports (3s)
[17:16:11]: [Merge dotCover reports] Started dotCover: C:\System\TeamCity\buildAgent\tools\dotCover\dotCover.exe merge C:\System\TeamCity\Agent007\temp\buildTmp\dotcover3528224551281727042.xml
[17:16:11]: [Merge dotCover reports] Output: JetBrains dotCover Console Runner v1.1.252.2. Copyright (c) 2009-2012 JetBrains s.r.o. All rights reserved.

[17:16:11]: [Merge dotCover reports] dotCover exited with code: -1073740940
[17:16:11]: [Merge dotCover reports] dotCover returned non-zero exit code.
[17:16:12]: Remove dotCover snapshot files
[17:16:12]: [Remove dotCover snapshot files] Started dotCover: C:\System\TeamCity\buildAgent\tools\dotCover\dotCover.exe delete C:\System\TeamCity\Agent007\temp\buildTmp\dotcover2466421969996709368.xml
[17:16:12]: [Remove dotCover snapshot files] Output: JetBrains dotCover Console Runner v1.1.252.2. Copyright (c) 2009-2012 JetBrains s.r.o. All rights reserved.

[17:16:12]: [Remove dotCover snapshot files] dotCover exited with code: 0
[17:16:12]: Generate dotCover report (3s)
[17:16:16]: [Generate dotCover report] Started dotCover: C:\System\TeamCity\buildAgent\tools\dotCover\dotCover.exe report C:\System\TeamCity\Agent007\temp\buildTmp\dotcover1373956647492282113.xml
[17:16:16]: [Generate dotCover report] Output: JetBrains dotCover Console Runner v1.1.252.2. Copyright (c) 2009-2012 JetBrains s.r.o. All rights reserved.

[17:16:16]: [Generate dotCover report] dotCover exited with code: -1073740940
[17:16:16]: [Generate dotCover report] dotCover returned non-zero exit code.
[17:16:16]: Generate dotCover HTML report
[17:16:16]: Packing snapshot files (3s)
[17:16:20]: [Packing snapshot files] Started dotCover: C:\System\TeamCity\buildAgent\tools\dotCover\dotCover.exe zip C:\System\TeamCity\Agent007\temp\buildTmp\dotcover128074978195207834.xml
[17:16:20]: [Packing snapshot files] Output: JetBrains dotCover Console Runner v1.1.252.2. Copyright (c) 2009-2012 JetBrains s.r.o. All rights reserved.

[17:16:20]: [Packing snapshot files] dotCover exited with code: -1073740940
[17:16:20]: [Packing snapshot files] dotCover returned non-zero exit code.
[17:16:20]: Remove dotCover snapshot files
[17:16:21]: [Remove dotCover snapshot files] Started dotCover: C:\System\TeamCity\buildAgent\tools\dotCover\dotCover.exe delete C:\System\TeamCity\Agent007\temp\buildTmp\dotcover1456730463762641811.xml
[17:16:21]: [Remove dotCover snapshot files] Output: JetBrains dotCover Console Runner v1.1.252.2. Copyright (c) 2009-2012 JetBrains s.r.o. All rights reserved.

Failed to obtain source files for the 'delete' command. File 'C:\System\TeamCity\Agent007\temp\buildTmp\dotCover9185619990474525744Merge' is nor a snapshot in supported format, nor a coverage results descriptor
[17:16:21]: [Remove dotCover snapshot files] dotCover exited with code: -2
[17:16:21]: [Remove dotCover snapshot files] dotCover returned non-zero exit code.
[17:16:21]: No statistics values are provided by dotCover report generator
[17:16:21]: Publishing artifacts
[17:16:21]: [Publishing artifacts] Paths to publish: [C:\System\TeamCity\Agent007\temp\buildTmp\coverage1694097105968668380zip\CoverageReport.xml=>.teamcity/.NETCoverage]
[17:16:21]: [Publishing artifacts] Sending files
[17:16:21]: Publishing internal artifacts
[17:16:21]: [Publishing internal artifacts] Sending build.finish.properties.gz file
[17:16:21]: Build finished
```

Comment: Whats frustrating is, there are no meaningful debug messages, that will allow me to go forward in debugging! JETBRAINSZZZZ!

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for the late answer. You could have such filters and that should be enough:

```
+:BSF*
-:BSF.UnitTest
-:BSF.IntegrationTests
```

Strange exit-code can mean that the console runner process crashed for unclear reasons. You can either try the latest console runner build (http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/DCVR/dotCover+2.2+Nightly+Builds) or update dotCover built in TC. In order to do that put a zip on the TC-server to the following path:
TeamCity \ webapps \ ROOT \ WEB-INF \ plugins \ dotNetRunners \ agent \ dotCover.zip (full path may vary)
This will automatically deploy it to all agents.
If that doesnt't work for you, please feel free to contact the support.